# How to create json for highstock

Tags: php, json, highcharts

i need chenge input json in this code :

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function(data) {
        // Create the chart
        $('#container4').highcharts('StockChart', {
            chart: {
            },

            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 1
            },

            title: {
                text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
                data: data,
                type: 'spline',
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

my problem is when change input json above script dont work !!!!!
my json string is :

```
?([[1159747200000,74.86],[1159833600000,74.08]]);
```

according highstock json string

Comment: `script dont work` -- how are we supposed to help you with that *'information'*? What doesn't work? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

json generation change to for EX:

```
json_encode("[[1159747200000,74.86],[1159833600000,74.08]]");
```

input json (data) change to :

```
$(function() {

        $.ajax({ 
            url: 'http://localhost/server/json.php', 
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) { 

                var data_arr = $.parseJSON( data );

               $('#container4').highcharts('StockChart', {
            chart: {
            },

            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 1
            },

            title: {
                text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
                data: data_arr,
                type: 'spline',
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }]
        }); 

            }
        });
});
```

Comment: Do you receive any errors ?Script and json is on the same domain ?